# Displaying a SharePoint List from another team site in Sharepoint Online (office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365

I'm looking for a solution for Office 365 and SharePoint Online like this:

[Code Project: Displaying a SharePoint List from another team site in Sharepoint Foundation 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93558/Displaying-a-SharePoint-List-from-another-team-sit.aspx)

I'm trying to display a SharePoint list from another team site, like in this article, but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **replicate** SharePoint lists between sites / site collections / installations, for SharePoint 2010 / Foundation on-premise and in the Microsoft cloud using the Cloud Connector for SharePoint found here:

http://www.layer2.de/en/products/Pages/Cloud-Connector-for-SharePoint-2010-Office365.aspx

See here how it works:

[image]